# How do I change date origin in libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, date, libreoffice-writer

I am copying a chart from a Calc file to a Writer file. The Calc file has a date origin of 1904. When I copy the chart to the writer file, all the dates get shifted because the origin is (I suppose) the default in Writer (1899).

I would like to know if there's a way to change the origin date in libreoffice Writer so that my charts' dates are respected ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Calculate#Date) and [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Date_%26_Time_functions), the `01/01/1900` and `01/01/1904` start dates are foreign formats, and those settings are only for importing into Calc.  So it is not a surprise that it would change when moved to Writer, or to another Calc document.

Instead, convert it to an image before moving to Writer.  To do this with dates preserved, I did the following:

1. File -> Print Preview, then close the preview.
2. Resize the chart so that it fits within the line shown by print preview.
3. File -> Export.  Save as PNG.
4. In Writer, go to Insert -> Image.

Alternatively, instead of using fixed images, you could:

1. Add a new sheet to avoid clutter.
2. On the new sheet, add columns in Calc with formulas that add 5 years and one day to the original data.
3. Copy and paste the original chart to create a second chart, and change it to use the data on the new sheet.
4. Copy and paste the second chart to Writer.

Comment: I ended up copying the whole sheet format to a new file with the default date origin and adding the necessary time delta to the date columns. Will wait a few more days before validating the answer, you never know.

Answer (score 0):

In Calc, double-click on the chart, then right-click on the date axis and choose `Format Axis` from the context menu.  Go to the Scale tab.  Is the type set to Automatic, or Date?

[image]

This is probably where the "1904" date is getting set.  You can set it to whatever value you wish.  In my example, the origin is 1342.

I copied it to Writer and it remained 1342, so I'm not sure why it changed in your document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jim_K, however it's not really about the origin of the axis but the date origin of the file, the one you find in the Tools > Options menu (under libreoffice calc > calculate). To see how this affects even Calc to Cacl copy/pastes, take a look at [this short video](https://vimeo.com/156675036)